# Pyspark/Databricks - org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

I'm trying to use Linear Regression on a simple dataframe with **one feature** and **one label** using Python pyspark in Databricks. However, I'm running into some issues with stage failure. I've reviewed many similar problems, but most of them are in Scala or are out of the scope of what I'm doing here.

**Versions:**

Notebook: Databricks 
5.3 (includes Apache Spark 2.4.0, Scala 2.11)
Python version: 2

**Here's what I've done:**

1. Original dataframe looks like this:

```
    df_red = df_extra.select('cca3', 'class', 'device_id').groupby('cca3').pivot('class').count()

    display(df_red)
```

[image]

I want the 'mac' column as my label and the 'other' column as my single feature.

2.Drop column 'cca3' and create label/feature

```
features = ['other']
lr_data = df_red.drop('cca3').select(col('mac').alias('label'), *features)
display(lr_data)
```

[image]

3. Create Vector Assembler and remove null values in dataframe

```
assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols = features, outputCol = "features")
output = assembler.transform(lr_data)
new_lr_data = output.select("label", "features").where(col('label').isNotNull())
new_lr_data.show()
```

[image]

4. Linear Regression Model Fit:

```
# Fit the model
lr = LinearRegression(maxIter=10, regParam=0.3, elasticNetParam=0.8)
lrModel = lr.fit(new_lr_data)

# Print the coefficients and intercept for linear regression
print("Coefficients: %s" % str(lrModel.coefficients))
print("Intercept: %s" % str(lrModel.intercept))

# Summarize the model over the training set and print out some metrics
trainingSummary = lrModel.summary
#print("numIterations: %d" % trainingSummary.totalIterations)
#print("objectiveHistory: %s" % str(trainingSummary.objectiveHistory))
#trainingSummary.residuals.show()
#print("RMSE: %f" % trainingSummary.rootMeanSquaredError)
#print("r2: %f" % trainingSummary.r2)
```

At this point I get the error below:

> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
>   Task 73 in stage 979.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task
>   73.0 in stage 979.0 (TID 32624, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined
>   function($anonfun$4:
>   (struct<other_double_VectorAssembler_a2059b1f0691:double>) =>
>   struct<type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int>,values:array<double>>)

What causes the above error to occur within Databricks? Could this be because I only used one feature as opposed to many features (usually the case)?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I may know what was the cause of the "org.apache.spark.SparkException: Writing job aborted" error.

- This error sometimes occur if your JAR version is incompatible with
  other JAR's
- And Other times The error usually occurs when there is memory
  intensive operation and there is less memory

I solved it by using this "neo4j_connector_apache_spark_2_12_4_1_2_for_spark_3.jar" and no other jar installed in my cluster and for the memory intensive calculation i used 500 Ram iwas using 224 ram when the problem accured